# `error: exception specification of 'operator()<Iterator>' uses itself` when dealing with string_view

Tags: c++, c++23

Consider following code:

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:26,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:26,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Astruct+Iter%0A%7B%0A++++Iter()+%7B%7D%0A++++Iter(std::string_view)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++Iter+begin()+const%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+*this%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:43.28981723237598,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2b%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:29.623619985624018,l:%274%27,m:49.21700223713646,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50.78299776286354,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:56.71018276762404,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <string_view>

struct Iter
{
    Iter() {}
    Iter(std::string_view) {}

    Iter begin() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

It's a stripped down iterator, which is supposed to be used as `for (auto x : Iter(...))` (exactly the same as [`fs::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin)). I've removed `end()` and all the overloaded operators for brevity, since they don't affect the error.

This code compiles with `-std=c++20` (with both GCC and Clang), but once I switch to `-std=c++2b`, GCC and Clang with libstdc++ reject it, while Clang with libc++ still accepts it.

Here's the gist of the error:

```
iterator_concepts.h:945:6: error: exception specification of 'operator()<Iter>' uses itself
...
string_view:153:7: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'contiguous_range<const Iter &>' requested here
...
string_view:153:15: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
          && ranges::contiguous_range<_Range>
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:16: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'basic_string_view<const Iter &, Iter>' required here
        return *this;
               ^
<source>:10:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view<const Iter &, Iter>' requested here
```

The error doesn't happen if the function isn't named `begin`. Apparently `return *this;` considers the `string_view` constructor, which checks some concepts for `Iter`, which includes checking the `begin` itself.

What is going on and how do I fix this error?

---

[Reported a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103951) for libstdc++.

Comment: The new [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) constructor would seem a likely suspect, probably hasn't been implemented in libc++ yet. Does making your string view constructor explicit help?

Comment: I would expect the range constructor to not be viable, since `Iter` does not model a contiguous and sized range. Seems this is not handled in SFINAE friendly way in GCC. Might be a bug.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It does, I'll probably do that for now.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'll file a bug then, and see what happens.

Comment: I can't say for sure how relevant it is, but this reminds me a lot of [this article](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/11/21/concepts-what-are-you-doing/) about a quirk in libc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code compiles with -std=c++20 (with both GCC and Clang), but once I switch to -std=c++2b, GCC and Clang with libstdc++ reject it, while Clang with libc++ still accepts it.

Clang 14 with libstdc++ fails to compile it because Clang 14 had a buggy implementation of concepts and cannot compile GCC's `<ranges>` header. Clang 15 with a recent version of libstdc++ compiles it OK.

GCC 12.1 failed to compile due to a cycle in constraint checks for one of `string_view`'s constructors. GCC 12.2 compiles OK, because it includes the change from [P2499R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2499r0.html) "`string_view` range constructor should be `explicit`".

tl;dr C++23 was still under development in January 2022 and support was patchy.